# How would I output every line for every label?

Tags: c#, windows

Thanks to the community help, I've been able to put in a dynamic label inside the tab control, saved the value to a list, and call it as I want to. Now move on to the next question, if I want to output every sing line for every dynamic label, how would I do that ?
Below is my code:

```
private void frmYourCart_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InvoiceRental.GetTitle().Count > 0)
    {
        //page 215
        for (int i = 0; i < InvoiceRental.GetTitle().Count; i++)
        {
            lblConsole.Visible = true;
            lblTitle.Visible = true;
            lblPrice.Visible = true;
            Label resultLabel = new Label();
            resultLabel.AutoSize = true;
            resultLabel.Location = new Point(160, 200);
            resultLabel.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);
            resultLabel.Text += String.Format("{0, 50} {1, 50}\n", InvoiceRental.GetTitle()[i], InvoiceRental.GetPrice()[i]);
            this.Controls.Add(resultLabel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can someon please edit my code please ? I was trying to find a button to put all the code inside, but could not find it. Thanks

Comment: thanks Mitch. I'll try to look for it next time

Comment: Your `if` statement is redundant, you can assume that `Count > 0` if you execute anything within the `for` loop. Do you need a unique label for each line or could you use a single label?

Comment: What I am doing is to output all the selected games that the customer wants to buy. So, I don't think I need a unique label for each line. What do you mean when you say I can assume that count > 0 ?

Comment: Guvante means that you can remove the if statement because it is redundant with the loop.

Comment: oh thanks. I did not notice it